# How do I list which possible errors a code is prepared to warn during an execution?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a logging for one of my codes and would like to add Exceptions that are specific to certain errors in order to know, by consulting the log, not only if something went wrong but also what went wrong.

Is there any way in python 3.x to consult/list which type of errors a given module is prepared to return (such as an integrity error) without having to consult the actual text or trying to crash the code on pourpose so I can start working on the Exeptions?

Thanks for your time,
Andre

Comment: No formal way, AFAIK; parsing the doc strings if the authors are careful, or even looking at the actual code, is your best bet.